# How do you use the value of the combobox selected item?

Tags: c#, combobox, port

I've written this code to change the `serialport` name:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {    
        serialPort1.PortName = (string)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("The SerialPorts's Name Does Not Change !! "); 
    }
}
```

The result is that I get an `Exception`. The `SerialPort`'s name never changes.

Comment: Can you post the Exception please?

Comment: The PortName cannot be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `SelectedValue` Mr. JaredPar MSFT explained [ComboBox SelectedItem, SelectedValue, SelectedWhat???](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2006/11/07/combobox-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedwhat.aspx).

I guess, your trying get the `PortName` not the `SelectedValue`

***Solution***:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBox1.Text)) return;
    serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
}
```

## or

your trying get the `SelectedValue` not the `PortName`

***Solution***:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == null) return;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBox1.Text)) return;
    serialPort1.PortName = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue ;
}
```

Try to check your properties of `ComboBox`

[image]

```
 Where: Display Member is your PortName
        Value Member is your PortId or SelectedValue
```

Comment: This does not check for String.Empty, nor does it check if the port is open. If the port is open you can't change the port name, although adding that check would be rather simple.

Comment: thanks the problem is solved ...
the port should be closed ??

Comment: about the `Port` thats another issue, our issue here is how to use the `value` of `comboBox`, about the port try this [Serial Port Communication In C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/#/) :)

Comment: BUT , why I don't see the changes in the properties window of the serialPort1 ?? since there is no any error .. why the properties haven't updated (--> properties window <--) ?

Comment: @Sho3a3_Elamal try to create another question and be more specific about your problem serialPort1, but before that try google it first :)

Answer (score 1):

Could be one of many issues.

1. Is `(string)comboBox1.SelectedValue` `String.Empty`?
2. Is `(string)comboBox1.SelectedValue` `null`?
3. Is serialPort1 open?

It would be easier to answer the question if we had the actual exception message, instead of the custom message you defined.

Comment: This is the exception : The PortName cannot be empty

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a check in to see if the SelectedIndex is -1 or SelectedValue (or SelectedItem) is null. That's the value when there is no selected item.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    serialPort1.PortName = (string)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to figure out what the exception message is, try this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {    
        serialPort1.PortName = (string)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't handle exception properly. The exception that is thrown probably tells you what is the problem, but you're not looking at it.

Change your catch statement to

```
catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); }
```

Then see what is the exception, and fix it accordingly.

The [SerialPort.PortName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.portname.aspx) setter can throw an array of exceptions, so you need to know which one is it.